# Display common name instead of URL

Tags: url

Using classic ASP

It creates text messages to the user phone
In the message I like to have a piece of text shown that, when clicked goes to a specific URL

Something like

Login  is displayed, but when clicked it would got to an actual URL

Comment: Output your URL in to the href attribute of a HTML anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this is all you are looking for.

```
<%
'---- Written in VBScript
dim strUrl
strUrl = "http://www.example.com"
response.write "<a href='"& strUrl &"'>Go to Example.com</a>"
%>
```